# 'Open' button disabled in 'Where used' for local copies

Tags: 2013, cme, 2013-sp1

In the CME, I click on the 'Where Used' button for a component in a 'master' publication. In the list of items, there is also a 'local copy' in a 'child' publication. When I select this local copy, the 'Open' button is disabled.
[image: Where used popup without system admin rights]
Any idea what might be the cause?

Some more information:

- We are on 2013 sp1
- If I click on 'Go to Location' and open the component from there, there is no problem. I have sufficient rights to open, edit and save the component (even without system admin rights).
  [image: Clicked 'Open location']
  [image: Open is not disabled in the context menu]
- The page containing the component is in the same publication as the 'Local copy' item, and for that item the 'Open' button is not disabled.
- The 'Local copy' component is Checked in (not openend or checked out by another user)
- The issue doesn't occur consistently: <strike>yesterday I was unable to reproduce the problem, this morning I did. After a restart of Tridion at noon, the problem was gone again.</strike> *Edit: it doesn't occur when having system admin rights* [image: Where used popup with admin rights]
- The issue is not specific for 1 component or publication, if it occurs, it occurs everywhere.
- The json that is returned ('Allow' and 'Deny' values are different for last item):

  - without system admin rights (open button disabled for last item in the list):

    ```
    <tcm:ListUsingItems xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:95-207826-64" Title="default.aspx" Allow="268511625" Deny="49766" Icon="T64L0P1" Type="64" Versions="2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25" IsNew="false" Publication="GSC BE  Master Website" Path="\GSC BE  Master Website\Site* Beleggen\Particulier" OrgItemID="tcm:95-34864-4"></tcm:Item>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:100-207826-64" Title="default.aspx" Allow="268511689" Deny="49702" Icon="T64L0P1" Type="64" Versions="1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13" IsNew="false" Publication="GSC BE FR Website" Path="\GSC BE FR Website\Site*revamp | Beleggen\Particulier" OrgItemID="tcm:100-34864-4"></tcm:Item>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:95-208603-64" Title="default.aspx" Allow="268511625" Deny="49766" Icon="T64L0P1" Type="64" Comment="Only old versions" CommentToken="OnlyOldVersions" Versions="1 2" IsNew="false" Publication="GSC BE  Master Website" Path="\GSC BE  Master Website\Site* Beleggen\Rabo Selecties" OrgItemID="tcm:95-34866-4"></tcm:Item>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:100-208598" Title="ART intro" Allow="384" Deny="268561007" Icon="T16L0P0" Type="16" Comment="Local copy" CommentToken="LocalCopy" IsNew="false" Publication="GSC BE FR Website" Path="\GSC BE FR Website\Building Blocks\Content* Beleggen\Particulier"></tcm:Item>
    </tcm:ListUsingItems>
    ```
  - with system admin rights (open button activated for last item in the list):

    ```
    <tcm:ListUsingItems xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:95-207826-64" Title="default.aspx" Allow="268511625" Deny="49766" Icon="T64L0P1" Type="64" Versions="2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25" IsNew="false" Publication="GSC BE  Master Website" Path="\GSC BE  Master Website\Site* Beleggen\Particulier" OrgItemID="tcm:95-34864-4"></tcm:Item>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:100-207826-64" Title="default.aspx" Allow="268511689" Deny="49702" Icon="T64L0P1" Type="64" Versions="1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13" IsNew="false" Publication="GSC BE FR Website" Path="\GSC BE FR Website\Site*revamp | Beleggen\Particulier" OrgItemID="tcm:100-34864-4"></tcm:Item>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:95-208603-64" Title="default.aspx" Allow="268511625" Deny="49766" Icon="T64L0P1" Type="64" Comment="Only old versions" CommentToken="OnlyOldVersions" Versions="1 2" IsNew="false" Publication="GSC BE  Master Website" Path="\GSC BE  Master Website\Site* Beleggen\Rabo Selecties" OrgItemID="tcm:95-34866-4"></tcm:Item>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:100-208598" Title="ART intro" Allow="268511689" Deny="49702" Icon="T16L0P0" Type="16" Comment="Local copy" CommentToken="LocalCopy" IsNew="false" Publication="GSC BE FR Website" Path="\GSC BE FR Website\Building Blocks\Content* Beleggen\Particulier"></tcm:Item>
    </tcm:ListUsingItems>
    ```

If you have any questions or need additional information, please ask. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try it in different browsers?

Comment: Yes, FireFox and IE11, problem is the same.

Comment: Can you try as system admin and see if you get this error? That way you will be able to zero in on whether it's a permission issue or not. Also try the refresh option in where used and see if the option gets enabled

Comment: Open the developer tools and check whether there's a javascript error in the console

Comment: @Vipin: As system admin, I do not get this error, so it seems to be a permission issue. What I don't understand is why I don't have permission (when I am not system admin), because it is possible to first click 'Go to location' and then open the component, which has the exact same result but requires to do extra actions.

Comment: @JaimeSantosAlcón: There is no javascript error, but the json that is returned differs based on whether I have system admin rights or not (different allow/deny values). I will add them to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted SDL Support. It is a bug in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1. They will let me know if/when a hotfix for this problem is released.

Comment: Hi, did you find a resolution for this issue please?

Comment: FYI, hotfix CM_2013.1.1.88798 addresses this issue

Answer (score 2):

The button is disabled if you do not have View or Edit permissions on the selected item. The allowed action bit of 384 means that you are only allowed to Publish and UnPublish it - so the button is disabled.

As to why the Content Manager claims that you are only allowed to do publishing related actions on it from the Where Used screen, but you can do it from the parent Folder, I cannot say. Perhaps you have stumbled on a defect.

I would suggest that you contact Customer Support regarding this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter, I will create a ticket with Customer Support.